# Geometry Nodes - Weight Paint is not affecting "Set Position" smooth

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to make a procedural terrain with GeoNodes. My weight paint is not affecting the Set Positions Node in the way, that it takes any weights into account for the translation/sculpting. It is only taking the group as a whole for that gruff and bold effect. And despite the facts the different weight-zones are perfectly working for example with the density of distributed points or the scale of instances.

I also tried to pipe the attribute into the Z value of the Offset. But it resulted in the same issue. I am working with Blender 3.2.

Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data type of the selection socket is boolean, so it's values will be either 0 or 1 (*false* or *true*). Float values are internally converted to boolean using the condition $X \gt 0$.

If what you want is to control what percentage of the translation will be applied, you will need to multiply the translation by the weight:

[image]

the color of a socket shows what data type it works with, if you can't see the difference (or it's really hard to see) between a float socket and a boolean socket (and maybe string sockets), you may have some colorblindness similar to mine.

The [Blender documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/nodes/parts.html) says that float sockets are gray, while booleans are pink:

> Float (gray):
>
> Indicates numeric value’s information. It can either be a
> single numerical value or a so-called “value map”. (You can think of a
> value map as a gray-scale map where the different amount of
> bright/dark reflects the value for each point.) If a single value is
> used as an input for a “value map” socket, all points of the map are
> set to this same value. Common use: Alpha maps and value options for a
> node.
>
> Boolean (pink):
>
> Used to pass a true or false value.

Comment: Ah perfect. It worked with the Vector Math Node set to Multiply. The result is now a smooth translation of the mesh form following the weights. Thank you very much.